# Error: There was an error while hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, loading, react-suspense, hydration

When I added a loading page inside my home directory I got these errors:

> 1-Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what
> was rendered on the server.
>
> 2-Error: There was an error while
> hydrating this Suspense boundary. Switched to client rendering.

Loading file code :

```
export default function Loading() {
    return <h2 className="global">Loading...</h2>;
}
```

Folder structure :

```
── src
 └── app  
   ├── [locale]   
   └── home 
     ├── page.tsx    
     ├── layout.tsx  
     └── loading.tsx
```

layout.tsx:

```
type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
  params: { locale: string };
};

async function getMessages(locale: string) {
  try {
    return (await import(`../../../dictionaries/${locale}.json`)).default;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return ['en', 'ar'].map((locale) => ({ locale }));
}

export default async function RootLayout({ children, params: { locale } }: Props) {
  const messages = await getMessages(locale);

  const lang = locale === 'ar' ? 'ar' : 'en'

  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <head>
         //head InFO
      </head>
      <NextIntlClientProvider locale={locale ? locale : 'en'} messages={messages}>
        <body>
          <div className={`main-wrapper-content`}>
            {children}
          </div>
        </body>
      </NextIntlClientProvider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

page.tsx:

```
export default function HomePage() {
    return (
        <section>


    
            <div className={style.headerStyle}>

                <NavBar />
                <Hero />
            </div>

            <About />
            <WhyChooseUs />
            < Services/>
            <BlogsComponentHome />
            <LatestNews />
            <Team />
            <Testimonial />
            <Booking />
            <FooterMain />

        </section>
    

    )
}
```

Comment: Problem is most likely coming from one of the components on the homepage, Without seeing those components its hard to know, the best thing would be to comment them out, and uncomment one by one till you find the culprit and upload it above.